# Group rows by Id and concatenate month & order_count as columns?

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, max, conditional-aggregation

Currently I have an orders table that is formatted with a row per month:

| id | order_month | order_count | order_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 2021-07 | 5 | 50 |
| 111 | 2021-08 | 10 | 50 |
| 111 | 2021-09 | 1 | 100 |
| 222 | 2021-07 | 8 | 80 |
| 222 | 2021-08 | 2 | 50 |
| 222 | 2021-09 | 1 | 80 |

Is there a way to format the SQL query so that the ouput has 1 row per `id`, and the other values are added as columns? E.g. something like:

| id | 2021-07_order_count | 2021-07_order_sum | 2021-08_order_count | 2021-08_order_sum | 2021-09_order_count | 2021-09_order_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 5 | 50 | 10 | 50 | 1 | 100 |
| 222 | 8 | 80 | 2 | 50 | 1 | 80 |

I think I am close with the following query:

```
SELECT 
    merchant_id,
    (CASE WHEN order_month = '2021-07' THEN order_count ELSE 0 END) as '2021-07-orderCount',
    (CASE WHEN order_month = '2021-07' THEN order_sum ELSE 0 END) as '2021-07-orderSum',
    (CASE WHEN order_month = '2021-08' THEN order_count ELSE 0 END) as '2021-08-orderCount',
    (CASE WHEN order_month = '2021-08' THEN order_sum ELSE 0 END) as '2021-08-orderSum',
    (CASE WHEN order_month = '2021-09' THEN order_count ELSE 0 END) as '2021-09-orderCount',
    (CASE WHEN order_month = '2021-09' THEN order_sum ELSE 0 END) as '2021-09-orderSum'
FROM orders
ORDER BY id
```

It is creating a separate column and putting the correct values in each column.

[image]

However when I try and group by Id it then only shows the first result:

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN order_month = '2021-07' THEN order_count ELSE 0 END) `2021-07-orderCount`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN order_month = '2021-07' THEN order_sum ELSE 0 END) `2021-07-orderSum`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN order_month = '2021-08' THEN order_count ELSE 0 END) `2021-08-orderCount`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN order_month = '2021-08' THEN order_sum ELSE 0 END) `2021-08-orderSum`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN order_month = '2021-09' THEN order_count ELSE 0 END) `2021-09-orderCount`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN order_month = '2021-09' THEN order_sum ELSE 0 END) `2021-09-orderSum`
FROM orders
GROUP  BY id
ORDER BY id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=63fd9349665ca3900b27f99ed6994d4c).